# Passing a PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

I have the following php code below...

```
if ($username == 'fredk')
{ $fname = 'Fred'; }
else if ($username == 'arbonk')
{ $fname = 'Arbon'; }
else if ($username == 'arsalana')
{ $fname = 'Arsalan'; }
else if ($username == 'minhn')
{ $fname = 'Minh'; }
else if ($username == 'nathanielg')
{ $fname = 'Nathaniel'; }

$msg = "Hi $fname, your login was successfull. <p></p>";
```

All i want to do is pass the $fname variable onto the next php page.  On the same page I also have a form and when the submit button is clicked it goes onto the next page.

Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: The questions gets confusing when you mention the form. Do you want to use the form to pass the value via a hidden input?

Comment: I don't get why people are downvoting the session answers. It is really the only way to do it. That or cookies.

Comment: Got your dupe right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: Those answers are more comments, if even half-done attempts at an answer. They're the equivalent of RTFM. @cha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into sessions. They're used for the exact reason in your example (persistent login credential data + more).

```
session_start(); // Do this at the very start of your script (on both pages).
$_SESSION['your_key_here'] = 'blah'; // value may be an object as well.
```

on the next page you can access it:

```
print_r($_SESSION['your_key_here']);
```

Comment: You don't have to use print_r() if you know the key, you can just echo $_SESSION['your_key_here'];

Comment: The point was to demonstrate that you can store various objects there as well, not simply primitives. 

Of course, there's nuances as some objects can't be serialized/pickled trivially.

Comment: I will need to look into how sessions works, thanks for you help and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into the session.

Comment: yeah, Im going to try and do something with session

Answer (score 1):

Session is the way to do that...

Comment: yeah, Im going to try and do something with session

Answer (score 1):

Or you can put the variable into the form as a hidden variable

```
<input type='hidden' name='who' value='$fname>
```

but, this is just for completeness sake,

I would probably use a session myself.

Comment: yeah, Im going to try and do something with sessions, thanks don

Answer (score 1):

use session variable and put the fname in session.

Comment: yeah, Im going to try and do something with sessions, thanks praveen

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use $_POST

for example if this is your form code:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <input name="fname" type="hidden" value="$fname" />
</form>
```

On page.php you would retrieve the fname variable like so:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
```

Comment: The name is already known; there's no need to enter it again.

Comment: Changed the type to a hidden field and used the name as the value.

Comment: since i already have another form on the page, i think that it makes more sense (for me at least) to try and use sessions as Koobz has advised.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `$username` come from? Could you perhaps write a function that takes `$username` as a parameter and returns `$fname`, and call it on both pages?