# How to pass data between pages

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Pass non-form variables between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100450/php-pass-non-form-variables-between-pages)

I have problem with passing data dynamically populated. The code below dynamically display the restaurant hours of operation. Now I want to pass this hours into new page.

```
while ($start <= $end)
        {
            $startIn = strtotime('+0 minutes',$start);
            $hourIn = ( date('h:ia', $startIn));

            //dispaly restaurant availability
            echo "<td id='td'>"."<a href='$resName.php' style='text-decoration: none;'>" . $hourIn ."</a>". "</td>";
            $start = strtotime('+30 minutes',$startIn);
        }
```

Comment: Do you know how to work with GET/POST data?

Comment: yes I can pass single data into another page however I dont konw how to use this in my situation.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)?

Comment: $_GET, $_POST or $_SESSION any global variable will serve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

You should use global variables as $_POST and $_GET:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

an Example of how to use `GET` method:

if you go from one page to another following a hypertextual link in which you put variable names and associated values separated by `=` symbol

```
<a href="resName.php?variable_1=$hourIn" >
```

you can acces value of variables like this and store it in local variables of your arrival page:

```
$local_var = $_GET['variable_1']
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your data by using GET (or POST) method

like following,

```
echo "<td id='td'>"."<a href='resName.php?hours=".$hourIn."' style='text-decoration: none;'>" . $hourIn ."</a>". "</td>";
```

in resName.php, you can get this data like following,

```
$variable=$_GET['hours'];
```

Comment: This only pass selected hour. What I want to do is to pass all openning hours.