# How can I store object class into a session in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I have an object class store into PHP session and then get it in my next page as variable. Could you help?

Here is my class.inc.php

```
class shop {

var $shoeType;
var $color;

    public function __construct() {

        $shoeTypeService = new ShoeTypeService();
        $shoe = $shoeTypeService->getAllShoes();
        $this->shoeType = $shoe[20];
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has already been asked and received a comprehensive answer.  Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page/872522#872522

Answer (score 12):

Once you instantiate the class you can assign it to the session (assuming it's started)

```
$_SESSION['SomeShop'] = new Shop();

or 

$Shop = new Shop();
//stuff
$_SESSION['SomeShop'] = $Shop;
```

Keep in mind that wherever you access that object you will need the Shop Class included.

Comment: You can start the session with `session_start()`

Comment: __auto_load will take care of ensuring correct class file is included

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083544/1150683) states otherwise: serializing is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 9):

**used this code
first page**

```
$obj = new Object();

$_SESSION['obj'] = serialize($obj);
```

**in second page**

```
$obj = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);
```

Comment: Does not work, it still says "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name" in the unserialized object.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply store an object instance into the session. Otherwise the object will not be appeared correctly in your next page and will be an instance of __PHP_Incomplete_Class.
To do so, you need to [serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your object in the first call and [unserialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) them in the next calls to have the object definitions and structure all intact.

Comment: serializing and unserializing is handled very well by php internally

Comment: to avoid the PHP_Incomplete_Class issue you need an autoloader.

Comment: You get an incomplete class only, when you didn't include the file of the needed class. Using an autoloader or using a function like `require_once()` should solve this problem.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083544/1150683) states otherwise: serializing is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Jakes answer It can be done with very little hassle like everything in php. Here is a test case:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['object'] = empty($_SESSION['object'])? (object)array('count' => 0) : $_SESSION['object'];
echo $_SESSION['object']->count++;
```

It will output count increased by 1 on every page load. 
However you will have to be careful when you first initiate the $_SESSION variable to check whether it is already set. You dont want to over write the value everytime. So be sure to do:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['SomeShop']))
    $_SESSION['SomeShop'] = new Shop();
```

or better yet:

```
if (!$_SESSION['SomeShop'] instanceof Shop)
    $_SESSION['SomeShop'] = new Shop();
```