# PHP Session in class output null

Tags: php, class, session

login.php

```
$yetkili = new YETKILILER();
$yetkili->YETKILI_TC=$YETKILI_TC;
$yetkili->YETKILI_SIFRE=$YETKILI_SIFRE;
$_void = $yetkili->Giris();
$_SESSION['YETKILI'] = $yetkili;
```

index.php

```
$yet =  $_SESSION['YETKILI'];
$tc= $yet->YETKILI_TC;
// Output $tc =null :/
```

Hello everyone. I'm trying to set up a class inside the sessions from php and request it from other pages but when I try to do that, I only get null. Could someone help me please? Thank you.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store object class into a session in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578679/how-can-i-store-object-class-into-a-session-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution2 login.php

```
$yetkili = new YETKILILER();
$yetkili->YETKILI_TC=$YETKILI_TC;
$yetkili->YETKILI_SIFRE=$YETKILI_SIFRE;
$_SESSION['YETKILI'] = serialize($yetkili);
```

index.php

```
 $yetkili =  unserialize($_SESSION['YETKILI']);
 $test = $yetkili->YETKILI_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a code piece about your Giris() method.
You need to set your session on this method. Then get session variables by session_start method.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

a possible explanation: before you get the YETKILI object back from the session with `$yet =  $_SESSION['YETKILI'];` you must ensure that the class definition for `YETKILILER` is available. i.e. in index.php, make sure you have used `include` or `require` on the file that holds the YETKILI class.

Answer (score 1):

Solution
login.php

```
   $yetkili = new YETKILILER();
   $yetkili->YETKILI_TC=$YETKILI_TC;
   $yetkili->YETKILI_SIFRE=$YETKILI_SIFRE;
   $_SESSION['YETKILI'] = serialize($yetkili);
```

index.php

```
     $yetkili =  unserialize($_SESSION['YETKILI']);
     $test = $yetkili->YETKILI_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include your class in the pages where you are accessing the object via the session. I suggest you create a separate file, eg class_lib.php, where you define all your classes and then use `include` or `require` in the pages that use it.

Also, you will need to serialize your object before assigning it to a session and then unserialize it on the other end.

EDIT: Also, you will need session_start(); in both pages or in a page that they both include.