# kohana pass value to redirected view

Tags: forms, redirect, kohana

I'm curious how to pass the value `$name` from the controller to the view `success.php`
if `$this->request->redirect ( 'success' );` is used. (it redirects to success.php if the name was entered on the previous page unless it stays on the same page).

View `success.php` contains:

```
Hello, <? echo $name; ?>!
```

Tried several ways to pass the value `$name`, but still have no luck. All the rest works fine (it redirects if the name is not empty). All I want is to write 'Hello, John', if 'John' was entered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the redirect set a session-variable with a key, like name:

```
$session->set('name', 'John');
```

After the redirect you call the variable with session->get_once();

```
$name = $session->get_once('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with Kohana but with basics of HTTP protocol.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page) post describes several possible solutions for your problem.