# how do I send data from one php file to another?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a button on a file test.php

```
<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Download" onclick="alert('<?php echo $url; ?>')">
```

when the file is clicked, it alerts the page's url.

I have another page, test2.php.

I want the url that is being alerted to be displayed out in test2.php

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want from one page to change another? it's impossible if I understand the question.

Comment: can you explain what exacly you want to do? i don't understand...

Comment: no just to send the file and output it on test2.php

Comment: You could use a form and POST that value to the next page.

Comment: You mean the contents of the file?

Comment: You need to make a form on page 1 that submits to page 2.  Set the value of a variable on that form to the URL and submit.  Then page 2 can read the form value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how important it is that it be a button, you could create a form that would send the $url in POST to test2.php. There are many workarounds, but one is the ever-elusive 'hidden' input.

The code on test.php would end up looking like:

```
<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<form action="test2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $url ?>" >
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="" onclick="alert('<?php echo $url; ?>')">
</form>
```

While the code on test2.php would have to include:

```
<?php $sent_url = $_POST['url']; 
      echo $sent_url;
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Mason

P.S. More information on other ways to do this can be found in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page).

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to pass data:

Your value:
`<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>`

### Forms hidden input field (POST | GET)

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $url;?>">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Change `method="POST"` to `method="GET"` for GET

### A Link (GET)

`<a href="page2.php?url=<?php echo urlencode($url);?>">Download</a>`

### Through a session

```
<?php 
session_start(); //First line of page1 and page2
$_SESSION['url']=$url;
?>
```

Then to get the value use the globals `$_POST` and `$_GET` or `$_SESSION` depending on which method you choose.

### Even webstorage javascript (HTML5):

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
    if (localStorage.passthis){
    //Already set, perhaps set it here on page1 and and display it here on page2
    }
    else{ //Not set
          localStorage.passthis = window.location.href;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Passed from page1.php: " + localStorage.passthis;
}else{
    //No web storage
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps, I suggest you do alittle research first before asking a question. [php.net](http://php.net) is your friend.

Comment: Thank you soo much Lawrence... can't understand why most people coud not understand my question. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data via a form GET or POST: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

```
Example URL: http://yoursite.com/page2.php?frompageone=Hello

echo $_GET['frompageone']; // Echos "Hello"
```

POST is more secure than GET, this is just a quick example.

Comment: Ohhh, **w3school link** watch out as several pissed off users move in. `:)`

Comment: Okay, so I'm not posting a link to http://w3fools.com.