# how to pass a 2D array variable from one php page to another

Tags: php, variables, multidimensional-array

I am working on a php project where I need to pass the value of 2D array from one page to another. Please help me.

Comment: You mean to send it from `form`?

Comment: can you paste the code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Serverside passing: if it is on the same server, store the array temporarily in $_Session or in a database. Otherwise: communicate it via Json...

It might help if you post the code that you already have...

Comment: 1st page is a login form with a function that generates grid(matrix) of random alpanumeric values. 2nd page is used to process 1st page from where session starts...I want to pass the GRID generated in 1st page to 2nd page..

Comment: Do you have something like Session variable? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: I got d solution..
on page 1: 
`$jk=base64_encode(serialize($finalgrid));
 <input type="hidden" name="grid" value="<?php echo $jk; ?>">`

on page 2:
`$finalgrid1=unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['grid']));`

I got the 2D array on 2nd page...