# need to use variables in another page

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Is it possible to use super global variables on another page. Basically I have two pages form.php and search.php. I'm calling search.php using ajax on submit button on-click also I am using method post and without action. If I try to use super global variable in search.php which is in form.php then it gives error for undefined variable.
I don't want to use session, cookies or $_get. I have to fetch data from MySQL using those vaiables.

Comment: I don't care if you don't want to use cookies, sessions or $_GET. Globals, even super globals, don't persist across requests. Full stop. Only cookies/sessions do or any data you pass in the URL/request itself. There's no alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include one page in another or create 3rd page with your variables.
Or you just use session superglobal.

Answer (score 2):

in place of global variable you can use session variables