# Is it possibile/good idea to create Multiple PHP pages/urls from a single PHP file

Tags: php

Im writing a gallery application in php that reads Facebook album data and creates individual photo albums. The main php file contains an array of albums which it uses to create a list the viewer can select from to open a specific album. What i want to do is keep the array central to a single file and have it create a separate page for each album.

the array is as follows

```
$albumList = array(
array(
    network => "facebook",
    path    => "393991930641111"
    cover   => "images/sculpture.png" 
),
array(
    network => "facebook" ,
    path    => "183578065022222"
            cover   => "images/photography.png"     
)
    //more array entries for each new album
)
```

the main PHP file uses this array to create a list, which you can click on to open each individual album.

I dont want to have to create a new php file every single time i want to add a gallery to the array.

Is there a way i can have the list created from the array use links like mysite.com/gallery/index.php&id=0 and this would load a unique page being functionally the same as a separate file itself? (it would just call a function passing the id to load the gallery/content it needs).

Comment: and yes, it's a great idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you're asking. One way is to use `$_GET` request. Just create a page called `gallery.php` and insert this at the top:

```
$albumListArray = $_GET['list-id'];
```

You need the pass the id into the `URL` and it will look something like this:

```
yoursite.com/gallery.php?list-id=
```

Here is a resource for you to learn more: [PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Comment: hmm thanks, i think this is what i was going for. So if i have one index.php file, and have <a> tags that link to "index.php?id=photography" its treated the same as if i had a separate file photography.php (ie: will web crawlers read these separate files if i have links to them?)

Comment: Yep and `SEO` is based on the links, like you wrote. Happy coding :)