# How can i pass a variable from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, isset

I am creating a website, that has many pages. You can change the number of posts shown in each page through a drop down menu. My problem starts if i change the amount of posts move to the next page it comes back to default.

e.x default posts shown is 30, and then i change it to 40. The moment i change page it comes down to 30 again on the next page.

I have tried something like that but unfortunately doesn't work.

```
<form method="get" name="SkipPage">
<select name="results_no" onChange="document.forms['SkipPage'].submit()"> `
<?php
....
?>
</select>
</form>
```

`$reults_no = isset($_GET['results_no']) ? $_GET['results_no'] : 30;`

Comment: `$reults_no` : a `s` is missing

Comment: Please, show more code.

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan I didn't understand exactly what you meant could please explain a bit more

Comment: re-read carefully the code you have pasted in the question

Comment: Oh thanks, maybe that was a factor but is not the solution sadly

Comment: Good answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use hidden intput

```
<input type="hidden" name="myHiddenVar" value="<?php echo $myVar ?>"
```

Then you can use your var with `$_POST["myHiddenVar"];`

But if you want a persistent choice use sessions.
`session_start();` on each page and access/edit your var with `$_SESSION['myVar'];`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a user choice persistent, the usual solution is to save it in a cookie.

EDIT: or in SESSION but my point is that you don't have to pass the value as a GET parameter for each link followed by the user. You set it once and test if set on each page that need it.