# Bring variable to second page

Tags: php

I need to bring a PHP variable to another page, how can I do this?

The question is how do I do this.

My problem is I don't know how to do this.

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: @meWantToLearn This method id not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a PHP session variable.

**To store it:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['variableName']=1;
?>
```

**To retrieve it:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "value=". $_SESSION['variableName'];
?>
```

Comment: Your second body of code will fail because of missing `session_start();`

Comment: Oops, thanks!  Edited my answer.  I usually have my session logic in a common file stored on all pages, that way I can manage my session data in one place.

Comment: Try outputting the $_SESSION variable to see what's wrong, like so:

    `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: I got it working, but I have another question now. I will post a link to that question here if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. as Scott said you can use sessions,
2. if you are talking about data from website forms -> then through _POST and _GET parameters ( easy reading -> http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_forms.asp )
3. you are in file 1.php , and you need a variable from file 2.php ( variable name $myvar ), "include '2.php';" or "require '2.php';" , now after you have done that you can use your variable

Comment: i find it ironic that they're teching PHP from an ASP.NET site

Comment: you have to know the enemy better than yourself :)