# Using PHP, how do I link a page and load it with a variable when clicked?

Tags: php, hyperlink

Using PHP, if I want to have the visitor click on their selected item, is it possible to have the name of that item passed to another page through the hyperlink?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and is a fundamental concept of php (and other web technologies). Consider php manual on [$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

You can find concrete example of usage from stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page), especially second part of the accepted answer should be interesting for you.