# In php, after starting a session then redirecting, do I need to start a session again?

Tags: php, session, redirect

So if I start a session on one page, then send information via `$_SESSION` should I put `session_start()` at the top of the new page?

For Example:

page1.php:

```
session_start();
# code makes $foo
$_SESSION["var"] = $foo;
header("LOCATION: page2.php");
die;
```

page2b.php:

```
$foo = $_SESSION["var"];
# code uses $foo somehow
```

Does page2.php need `session_start.php` at the beggining of it? Especially if the only way to access it was through a page that starts a session?

Comment: You need `session_start()` whenever you want to use session variables in that page, so yes

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Comment: Okay thanks kingkero, I just wasn't clear and I couldn't find a direct answer to this question anywhere. Not really a duplicate, as that question is asking about sending variables with forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... in every page you should start a session

Comment: thanks, I know it was a dumb question, but I wanted to make sure.