# Transferring processed value of 1 variable from one php file to another php file

Tags: php, variables

How can I transfer my processed value of 1 variable from php file A to php file B?

I can't use `include` because I've got a lot of html in there. When I use that my tables get duplicated.

Comment: I think sessions are for constants?

Comment: You just want to transfer the variable from one php file to another right ??

Comment: this link may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: Oh thanks to all of you :) I already did it. Yey!