# Pass php variables from one file to another

Tags: php

Hello guys have a question, how can i pass one php variable, from a php file to another. I got imagen-ajax.php a variable call $src, and i need that value in registrar.php to save the value in a db field. How can i do this?

The code in image-ajax.php executes first, and i need a variable from this file in registrar.php.

Here is mi code imagen-ajax.php:

```
<?php
include 'imgcamacho.lib.php';

if (isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    //$nombre = $file["name"];
    $nombre = getUniqueName();
    $tipo = $file["type"];
    $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];
    $size = $file["size"];
    $carpeta = "upload/";
    switch ($tipo) {
        case 'image/jpg':
            $tipo = JPG;
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $tipo = JPEG;
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $tipo = PNG;
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $tipo = GIF;
            break;
        default:
            die("Error, el archivo no es una imagen"); 
    }
    $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
    move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
    changeSize($src, 500, $tipo);
    echo "<img src='$src'>"; 

}else {
    die("No se ha cargado ningún archivo");
}
```

Here is mi code registrar.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$tipo_bolsa = $_POST['tipo_bolsa'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];

$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

$sueldo = $_POST['sueldo'];

$idP = $_POST['idP'];

// I need imagen-ajax variable $src, to save it on image field

require('cone.php');
$con = Conectar();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, :imagen, :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)';
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':imagen'=>$imj, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));
```

Comment: Yes, but this php files are just proccess, i mean if i do it for url the user has to click that url right? or the url can by ejecute it by itselt?

Because my php files do not get involve with the user, so the url can´t by clicked...

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. The ajax code is going to be where? Is not a simple way to do this?, using, includ or require by php?

Comment: Thats right i dont wanna by re direct to other page, i just need to pass that variable, i don´t really understand sorry, i'll think this would be easier.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: And how do i get the variable? or php just detect it? And another problem bro i do this include ('../imagen-ajax.php'); at top of registrar.php and the sql sentence do not execute

Comment: Ok thank you, i take a look at it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Comment: try to work with sessions...