# how to pass value from one page to another page in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have two page first one is **customerdetail.php** then second one is **package.php**. I have to pass data from customerdetail.php to package.php. There are three input types

---

**customerdetail.php**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/><br/><br/>
  <select id="item" class="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="date" name="Date" id="name" placeholder="Date" required/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

---

**Expected output in package.php**
Name

Email
3
Date

Comment: use `<form action="package.php" method="post">....your code ... <input type='submit' name="submit" valuse="Submit"></form>`

Comment: use form. provide package.php URL in action. When you will submit the form, you can get all the values in package.php in $_POST variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use POST method to send data to another page.

```
    <div>
<form method="POST" action="package.php" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/><br/><br/>
  <select id="item" name="select" class="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="date" name="Date" id="name" placeholder="Date" required/><br/><br/>
</form>
<div id="Result"></div>
</div>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: package.php,
               data: $("#myform").serialize(), 
               success: function(data)
               {
                   $('#Result').html(data); 
               }
             });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    }); });
    </script>
```

AND IN package.php php use below code

```
$name =$_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$select = $_POST['select'];
$date= $_POST['Date'];
echo($name. "<br/>".$email. "<br/>".$select. "<br/>".$date);
```

Comment: but it is redirecting me to package.php i dont want to redirecting.

Comment: If you don't want to be redirected to `package.php`, then where are you expecting the output?

Comment: You will need to use Ajax

Comment: I have updated the code. please make sure you include latest jquery code.