# how to Send Id to another page in php?

Tags: php

I have attendance management system in which two tables attendance and employees.
In this system a page that display all names of employees and make this as hyperlink shown below

```
<?php echo "<a href='attendance_add.php'>" . $row['emp_name'] . "</a> "; ?>
```

But I want to send employee_id to attendance_add.php page.
So how can i send?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like :

```
<?php echo "<a href='attendance_add.php?id=".$row['employee_id']."'>" . $row['emp_name'] . "</a> "; ?>
```

and then you will catch id from url with `$_GET['id']` inside of `attendance_add.php`

Answer (score 0):

in a href you write this:

```
<?php echo "<a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $id?> ">VIEW</a>"; ?>
```

then, you can fitch id on the new page with it:

```
$link = explode("=", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$id = array_pop($link);
```

or using GET SUPERGLOBAL:

```
$_GET['id'];
```