# How to pass a variable from one php to another

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm having a problem.

I have two PHP Scripts and I'm trying to pass a variable from `home.php` file to `friend_home.php`.

`home.php` script:

```
'<a href="friend_home.php?value='.$friend_row['username'].'">'<?php echo $friend_row['username'] ;
?>'</a>'
```

`friend_home.php` script:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['value'];
a?>
```

But I'm getting this as output:

> '.$friend_row['username'].'

and not the actual value itself.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: echo for the a tag maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know two things:

- The php code start with `<?php` and end with `?>`.
- You can output one variable with `echo`.

So, if you're out of the `<?php` tag, and you want output a variable, you need to do something like this:

```
<a href="friend_home.php?value=<?php echo $friend_row['username']; ?>">
<?php echo $friend_row['username']; ?>
</a>
```

Even better, since you've a query string parameter, you may want url-encode it, and use `htmlspecialchars` to the username.

```
<a href="friend_home.php?value=<?php echo urlencode($friend_row['username']); ?>">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($friend_row['username']); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for rectifying me :) That helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your link isn't formatted properly, try this instead:

`<?php echo '<a href="friend_home.php?value='.$friend_row['username'].'">'.$friend_row['username'].'</a>'; ?>`