# Get saved info in variables to another page

Tags: php

I saved inputs from this form to another php page as variables. How can I get those variables to into a different page with `<title>$title</title>.`

Basically transfer variables from one page to another with the same info.

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form  action="action.php" method="POST">
      <p>Video Title</p>   <input type="text" name="title"> <br>
     <p>Video Link</p> <input type="text" name="Link"> <br>
     <p>Description</p> <input type="text" name="desc"> <br>
     <p>Page Name</p>   <input type="text" name="pagename"> <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

ACTION.PHP (Saved Variables)

```
$title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
$link = htmlspecialchars($_POST['link']);
$desc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['desc']);
$pgname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pagename']);
```

VIDEO.PHP

```
    <title><?php  echo $_POST["$title"]; ?></title>
```

Comment: Use $_SESSION or cookies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_SESSION to use the variables to another page

```
action.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['title']= htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
// all the other variables


video.php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['title'];
```

Comment: you have to specify about the start of the session in each page.

Comment: @FrayneKonok yes session_start() has to be called in the top of each php page

Comment: modify the answer with `session start`.

Comment: @KryometricGaming sessions are permanent till you close the browser or you destroy them using session_destroy()

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the way you can do it, But `$_SESSION` is the best for doing this.

**Action.php**

```
$title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
$_GET['title'] = $title;
```

**Video.php**

```
<title><?php echo $_GET["title"]; ?></title>
```

If you interested on `$_SESSION` then, initialize / start the session in each page, set the session in `action` page and get the session from `video` page. for more: [visit](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use Session Variables. Making sure to start a new session on each page.For example, if you want to transfer variables from action.php to video.php, do the following:

```
/* In Action.php*/
session_start();
$_SESSION['title']= htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
/*Do the same for the rest of variables */

/*In Video.php*/
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['title'];
/*Do the same for the rest of the variables you saved in the Session super global array in 'action.php'
```