# need to paas value from one page to another in php

Tags: php, html

am fresh to coding, so please advice if i had done any mistake.

I am having 2 pages, one am using to input the value and the other need to display the value.i had created the input page with one text box and submit button, once i click submit button the text box content should go to the next page and display the value.

this is the second page where values should come and display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvw1q.png)

This is the first page am entering values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3PKI.png), in this i had add one submit button

Kindly help and advice
thanks in advance

Comment: use query string `$_GET` to pass values to other pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Comment: You should post your code to show what you have attempted by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use session in php to do it, in the first php file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['var']=yourValue;
```

now in the second php file:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['var'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First write your form with with get method like

```
<form method="get" action="second.php">
  <input name="text_field_name1" value=""/>
  <input name="text_field_name2" value=""/>
</form>
```

than you form value pass second page with url.

You can get value from second page by echo `$_GET['text_field_name1'];` and echo `$_GET['text_field_name2'];`