# update DIV content in another page (same domain)

Tags: jquery

Running a php page (PageA) which receives post information from a 3rd party. Code on page determines whats important etc. If this page then needs to dynamically update a div with relevant content on a second page (PageB) (which is viewable by a user on the same domain), how best to use jquery.append to do this ?

Question is what code do I now need on PageB to receive and update DIV dynamically (not written to a DB, only visible during the time the page is on the users screen ?

Thanks for any insights!

PageA is sending information to PageB

```
data = {'action': 'message', 'status': status, 'date': date};
```

`

```
$.ajax({
        cache:false,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'PageB.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data Send");
            $('#tester').append(data);
            }
    });
```

PageB is receiving post:

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        // Call the function which gets and displays the thumbnails
        if ($_POST['action'] == 'message') {
            code?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Comment: You need to either store the the data in a cookie and have the user request page b again, or put it in session and use ajax long polling on page b

Answer (score 0):

you can use html() instead of append() for replace content with new content

```
$('#tester').html(data);
```