# Inserting Variables Received from POST in PHP

Tags: php, variables, post

So I have a PHP page (labeled `page_2`) that is being passed data from a POST request from a form from another page (`page_1`) (let's label them `form_1` and `form_2`. Let's say `form_1` hold the data `data_1` and `form_2` holding `data_2`.

As for the script, I'm attempting to insert the data from both `form_1` and `form_2` into a variable defined via `page_2`.

So far I have the following:

```php
<?php
$var = "alpha=$_POST['form_2']&beta=$_POST['form_2']"
echo $var
?>
```

The expected output is:

```
alpha=data_1&beta=data_2
```

However, I get no output. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your form code...

Comment: Array keys inside of a double-quoted string should not have single quotes. Try `$_POST[form_2]`, or surrounded the variable with curly brackets `{$_POST['form_2']}`

Comment: You've got syntax errors in your code. You can run `php -l <file>` from the command line to perform a syntax check, or enable error reporting so that you get runtime errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: This also might be helpful - on multi-paged forms: https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/multi-page-forms-php

Comment: "[Q]uoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax" -[Complex (curly) syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: Minor formatting improvements