# Getting variable value from another page

Tags: php

I was trying to get variable value from a page and echo it out in another page
for example I have 2 pages `pg1.php` and `pg2.php`:

On pg2.php I have:

```
<?php
$vr = "Hello";
?>
```

Now I want to echo this out on pg1.php, I have tried this:

```
<?php
require "pg2.php";
echo $vr;
?>
```

It works, but the problem is whatever else I have on pg2.php will be displayed on pg1.php.

Comment: That's what a `require` does - it `include`s and evaluates that file. Not sure why you would think any differently considering the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) states exactly this - "***`require` is identical to `include`** except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error.*")

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page) might help.

Comment: @esqew yes sir i know. i am just trying to get help here.

Comment: @jibsteroos sorry sir but i don't want to use $_POST or $_GET or seassons or cookies. i am sure it can be done some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to restructure your code so that variables are defined in one file that then includes another file with output etc.

```
<?php
// vars.php
$vr = "Hello";
?>

<?php
// pg1.php
require "vars.php";
echo $vr;
?>

<?php
// pg2.php
require "vars.php";
// other stuff
// ...
// ...
?>
```

But for this issue in general, buffer output and then delete the buffer:

```
<?php
// pg1.php
ob_start();
require "pg2.php";
ob_end_clean();
echo $vr;
?>
```

Comment: amazing. thanks a lot sir.

Comment: hi. hope if you can help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806872/output-files-from-multiple-folders thanks.