# output files from multiple folders

Tags: php

is there a way to output a folder and its files like this using php

this is my directories

folder/12345/file1.php

folder/46745/file1.php

folder/57756/file1.php

i tried this ...

```
$a = glob("folder/*");

foreach ($a as $key) {

    echo $key."<br>";

}
```

but the output will be like this

```
folder/12345

folder/46745

folder/57756
```

i am trying to make output to be more like ...

```
folder/12345

file.php

folder/46745

file1.php

folder/57756

file.php
```

my point is how many file is inside a folder should be outputted below the folder. hope some one help me with this. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recursively iterate through files in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909820/how-to-recursively-iterate-through-files-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You want scandir: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

```
scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] ) : array

Returns an array of filenames on success, or FALSE on failure.
```

Example:

```
$dirArr = ['folder/12345', 'folder/46745', 'folder/57756'];

foreach($dirArr as $dir){
    $fileArr = scandir($dir);
    echo $dir.'\r\n';
    print_r($fileArr);
    echo '\r\n';
}
```

Result:

```
folder/12345
file1.php
file2.php

folder/46745
file1.php

folder/57756
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your time. have you tried this ? cause it is not working for me. it is outputted same as my own code. not as you showing in results as it should be.

Comment: @student98735 Think you're looking for it to be recursive. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#110570

Comment: @student98735 I don't have access to your files, but if you have files in a folder passed to `scandir()`, it will return an array of those file names.

Answer (score 0):

Get the directories, loop them, get the files and their `basename` and implode on `<br>`:

```
foreach(glob("folder/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    echo "$dir<br>";
    echo implode("<br>", array_map("basename", glob("$dir/*"))) . "<br>";
}
```

Or have a look at the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).