# How to pass data from one page to another in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass an id from a button in page1 to a variable that's in php in page2. The id is dynamic because there will be multiple buttons and i only need to send the clicked button id. The problem is I don't know where to start really. Do I need to use cookies? I have read some people use sessions but that is a bit overkill I think.

This is the button in page1

```html
<td class="button-table">
     <button class="leads-more-info-btn" 
     id="<?php echo $leadKey = $allIssues->key ?>" 
     onclick="sendData(this.id)">Apply..
     </button>
</td>
```

As you can see i tried using the `onclick`, but that is in javascript. I would like to do it in php.
And the variable name in Page2 is called `$currentLead`. So to summarize `page1:buttonID->page2:$currentLead`.

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: You can use a link instead of a button, and put a $_GET variable in the url with the id value

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely use `$_SESSION` as has been mentioned, but I'm fairly sure that you could also refactor your page so that your buttons are either contained in a `<form>`, or use AJAX to do a `$.get()` or `$.post()` to the other page's URL when the button is clicked. You could then check `$_GET` or `$_POST` to find/retrieve the values in that page.

A hyperlink to the new page (instead of a button) would work as well. You could simply pass the id in the querystring at that point, and could even style the hyperlinks to look like buttons with CSS if you want to keep the look/feel of a button.

Comment: There are some good ideas here, but just be careful storing things in the session - the session is supposed to persist so only save stuff in it you need to persist.  I.e. if you need the id only on that page and then not again (e.g. viewing a profile rather than loading a user) then the query string parameter may be a better choice

Comment: Yay, I can post comments now! Anyway, I agree with @jameson2012 and would not personally use the session option for this.

Answer (score -1):

Store it in a $_SESSION, Then use header() function if you want to get redirected to page2