# PHP. How to get selected date/time?

Tags: php, html

I would like to know how I can transfer my selected time/date from one page to another?

My HTML part looks like that:

```html
<form action="http://localhost/HTMLIeskotiAutomobiliu.php" method="post">
<label for="paemimo_laikas">Automobilio paėmimo laikas:</label>
<input type="time" id="paemimo_laikas" name="paemimo_laikas">
</form>
```

I tried same thing as I did with selected option (`<?php echo $_POST['time']?>`) but it didn't worked. So I'm looking for yours help.

Comment: Have you tried `<?php echo $_POST['paemimo_laikas']; ?>`? Afterall, `paemimo_laikas` is the name of that input field.

Comment: Oh yea, thats works, but can I make this value as default like when you open that page you see selected time and if you want you can choose another.

Comment: Learning to search is a super power when you are starting out.  Even vague terms like "*php variable another page*"  turn up many answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks everyone for answers and sorry for disturibing, I just wanted to know how to transfer selected time in the place where you can select time. I found out everything I was needed to do is put php sentence in value.

Something like that:

```
<input type="time" id="paemimo_laikas" name="paemimo_laikas" value="<?php echo $_POST['paemimo_laikas']?>">
```

Comment: You may also use `PHP's short echo tag` instead of the normal `<?php echo '....' ?>` like so : `<input type="time" id="paemimo_laikas" name="paemimo_laikas" value="<?= $_POST['paemimo_laikas'] ?>">`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I can do that!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the current time you can add a js script, like this:

```js
$(function(){     
  var d = new Date(),        
      h = d.getHours(),
      m = d.getMinutes();
  if(h < 10) h = "0" + h; 
  if(m < 10) m = "0" + m; 
  $("#paemimo_laikas").each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr({"value": h + ":" + m});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="time" id="paemimo_laikas" name="paemimo_laikas">
```

Comment: 1) OP is clearly taking their first steps with PHP.  There is absolutely no reason to involve Javascript. 2) This does not actually answer OP's question. 3) Why iterate with `.each()` over a single element?

Comment: I read the comments - "*when you open that page you see selected time*". **Not** current time, **selected** time.  OP is trying to select a date on one page, and then display that date on the next page.  Since this answer does not come close to answering the OP's question, I think that is a clear case for a downvote.